How to set the springboot configuration file to achieve the effect of java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
The UTF-8 environment is configured in idea, but how to achieve this effect without using -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 after packaging and running? The version of springboot is 2.2
server 
 servlet:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
  tomcat:
    uri-encoding: UTF-8
spring:
  http:
    encoding:
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
      enabled: true

None of these configurations achieve the desired effect

Thanks for the reminder, I will pay attention to the formatting issue in the future

With JDK18 the default should to be UTF8, unless you have something that sets it explicitly to something else.

I'm using jdk8, which defaults to the character set of the current environment, but I've reconstructed the image according to -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

You can opt for a JVM level encoding using JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Here is how to do it:
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Otherwise, your application.yml configuration looks correct. The other things you could probably add are the following:
spring:
    mvc:
        jsp:
            charset: UTF-8

If you are using thymeleaf, you could add this as well:
spring:
    thymeleaf:
        encoding: UTF-8


Thank you for your answer. The main problem here is that the character set is abnormal in the docker environment. I have rebuilt the image based on -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8.
